# How to decode ogg audio file to raw audio data?

Tags: c++, c, audio, ogg, vorbis

I have `.ogg` file and I want to decode it to raw audio data. I read documentation to `libvorbis`, but it's very brief and not clear. I don't understand it! What Should i use `libvorbis` or `libogg`? Or something else?

Answer (score 5):

`ogg` is file format so using `libogg` you can `demux` file and then you will get  vorbis audio you need to further decode that using `libvorbis`. and you will get raw audio.

Samples application for using those library are available on Internet.

Comment: So I have to first use libogg to extract vorbis data from ogg page and then use libvorbis to decode it to raw data?

Comment: yess...100% you get it.